# React Vite.js project on github pages

Tags: reactjs, seo, vite

Can someone tell me how to make Vite.js React app pages searchable in google. I know about dynamic nature of React app and problems with seo. I deployed simple react app to github pages and planning to add 4-5 pages to it. Is it possible at all (probably using react router and react-helmet) to make every of these 5 pages searchable provided there is some unique text on each of the pages.

I use vite.js since there are issues in deploying Next.js on github pages, but I am looking forward to advices how to make my app each page contain meta tags, which as I understand possible with SSG in my case.